# MS access SQL help

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this table:

```
beneficiary     service   marks   term
1               eng        50       1
1               eng                 2
1               math       30       1
1               math       20       2
1               com                 1
1               com        70       2
2               com                 1
2               com        30       2
2               eng        20       1
2               eng        30       2
```

How can I extract only the rows for **beneficiary** / **service** pairs that have **marks** in both **terms** in a **service**?

So from this table it should return only:

```
beneficiary     service   mark     term
1               math       30       1
1               math       20       2
2               eng        20       1
2               eng        30       2
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. What does "has marks in both term in a service" mean?

Comment: if you look at the second table it should make sense

Comment: And the 'service' column corresponds to these exams?

Comment: I have been staring at the second table for the last 6 minutes, and believe me, it doesn't make sense yet!

Comment: Ah, I think it's making sense now... 'service' means school year,or similar eh?

Comment: @Flimzy - I think `term` is for the semesters, and `service` is for the subjects and `mark` is for their grades.

Comment: @Ali - Can you give us the datatype of each column/field?

Comment: @domanokz all number except services is text,

Comment: +1 because now the question actually makes sense... and I think it's a good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works when I import your data into my local database and run it:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM scores AS s
JOIN (
    SELECT beneficiary,service
    FROM scores
    WHERE marks IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY beneficiary,service HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) AS x ON (x.beneficiary = s.beneficiary AND x.service = s.service);
```

Output:

```
 beneficiary | service | marks | term
-------------+---------+-------+------
           1 | math    |    30 |    1
           1 | math    |    20 |    2
           2 | eng     |    20 |    1
           2 | eng     |    30 |    2
(4 rows)
```

Comment: can't we do it using sub queries,

Comment: i almost have it in my mind, and almost sure that i need subquery to do it

Comment: @Ali i think you can use a view for the subquery and join the view with the table

Comment: @Flimzy : i meant it would use something like "where b_fid in (select ..... where)"... although the COUNT() trick is very helpful it might be my missing link

Comment: The problem with a simple WHERE .. IN (SELECT .. ) is that you can't constrain on two columns that way.  You need to constrain on two: beneficiary, service.  This is why a JOIN is necessary.

Comment: @Flimzy is right. Comment: @Flimzy you can use concatenation and use IN, but nobody would suggest that since indexes won't be used and performance would suffer

Comment: @niktrs: That should probably go in a separate answer, not in a comment. Also, it doesn't work :)